# Show/Hide Div by clicking another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide

I am a beginner at javascript and I wrote a simple code trying to show/hide a div simply by clicking on another div. If someone can check the code I wrote and correct me I would be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

```
$('DivBlue').ready(function() {
    $('DivRed').on('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('DivBlue').style.display = 'block';
    });
});
```

```css
.DivRed{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:15vw;
  height:15vw;
  background-color:red;
}

.DivBlue{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:15vw;
  height:15vw;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DivRed"></div>
<div class="DivBlue"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the *[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)* function in the jQuery library. `toggle()` with no arguments is a to shortcut show/hide an DOM element.

Also, it is good practice to use `.ready()` on the document instead of an element of the DOM.

So, your JS code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.DivRed').on('click', function(){
        $('.DivBlue').toggle();
    });

});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/53f4Lf18/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Toggle does the trick in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.DivRed').on('click', function() {
     $('.DivBlue').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your JavaScript with this and it will surely work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.DivRed').click(
           function() {
     $('.DivBlue').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making few mistakes here,

1. You cant get a div by a class name with `document.getElementById()` method. You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName()` method.
2. `document.getElementsByClassName()` return a [NodeList](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/NodeList). You can't apply CSS for a NodeList. So you need to select a Node to apply CSS using `document.getElementsByClassName('DivBlue')[0]`

To work your code should be changed as

```
$('DivBlue').ready(function() {
    $('DivRed').on('click', function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('DivBlue')[0].style.display = 'block';
    });
});
```